# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Bad'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, spyder, data-analysis

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
df = pd.read_csv('CarSeats_Dataset.csv')
df=df.dropna()
dummies=pd.get_dummies(df[['ShelveLoc', 'Urban', 'US']])
X = df.drop('Sales',axis=1)
y = np.log(df['Sales'])
X_train, X_test , y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 42) 
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I was trying to predict the Sales but when tried to fit the regressor I got the error :  <ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Bad'/>
I am a beginner in this and I do not know how to fix it. Can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: you need to convert string values to vector embeddings using tf idf, w2v etc in case of text. For category: one hot encoding

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

Data = {'Product': ['ABC','XYZ'],
          'Price': ['250','270']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)

print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

Comment: Consider explaining what your code does exactly, this helps OP and future readers more than just code with no context